# what is the possible reason behind getting negative UTC time?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

```
m_date - (moment.tz.zone('America/New_York').offset(m_date) * 60000);
```

This is the code that I am using, I am actually passing a date and returning the above value. Library used is : moment-timezone

Comment: What's the value of `m_date`?

Comment: What do you mean by a negative UTC time? Can you edit the question and add more details? Value of `m_date`, current output, expected output etc? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative times represent time before the year dot, 1970.

If m_date is before 1970 then this would make sense.